# R - how to run a calculation stored in variable

Tags: r, formula

If I have an arithmetic formula stored in a character vector, how can I get R to run it?
i.e:

```
> the_character
[1] "282 * 480 - 129"
```

The result above is a character type. Simply putting as.numeric(the_character) results in NA:

```
> as.numeric(the_character, na.rm = TRUE)

Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

I know I can just copy and paste that in to the console but I want to know if there is a way to do it automated as part of a script?

Comment: try this `eval(parse(text=the_character))`

Comment: you might be interested in the [Ryacas package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Ryacas/vignettes/Ryacas.pdf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using `eval` and `parse` (as mentioned in the comments):

```
eval(parse(text=the_character))
```

but be aware of the following:

```
> library(fortunes)
> fortune(106)

If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question.
   -- Thomas Lumley
      R-help (February 2005)
```

Your example is fairly benign, but if you are allowing others to determine the string for you to parse then you are opening a major security hole.  Even if you are constructing the string yourself and are sure that it is safe, this approach is prone to hard to find bugs.

If you can give us more information on how your string is being constructed and what your eventual goal is, then we may be able to suggest methods that will accomplish what you want in a much better way.

Comment: Thanks. I am constructing the formula from scraping a HTML page to construct a url for next part of an online exercise.